# "Authentication Credentials Invalid" when setup GCP Composer(Airflow) SMTP server

Tags: google-cloud-platform, smtp, airflow, google-secret-manager

I am using GCP Composer (Airflow) to run some scheduled tasks. And using AWS SES SMTP server to send notification email.

According to GCP Composer's document [Configuring your environment with Secret Manager](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/secret-manager#configuring_your_environment_with) and [Configure an SMTP password for a third-party SMTP service](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/configure-email#smtp_password), I set the Airflow configuration overrides as below

```
secrets
    backend airflow.providers.google.cloud.secrets.secret_manager.CloudSecretManagerBackend

smtp
    smtp_port 587
    smtp_mail_from ...
    smtp_host email-smtp.us-west-1.amazonaws.com
    smtp_starttls True
    smtp_password_secret smtp-password
    smtp_ssl False
    smtp_user ...
email
    email_backend airflow.utils.email.send_email_smtp
```

And add a secret entry `airflow-variables-smtp-password` in Secret Manager.

Airflow has an error when send the email:

```
...
Authentication Credentials Invalid
```

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR
It is a mistake in GCP document [Configuring your environment with Secret Manager](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/secret-manager#variables). The prefix are different in these two backends. You need to use prefix `airflow-config` for backend `airflow.providers.google.cloud.secrets.secret_manager.CloudSecretManagerBackend`, and `airflow-variables` for backend `airflow.contrib.secrets.gcp_secrets_manager.CloudSecretsManagerBackend` to access the secret in SecretManager. So my secret name in SecretManager should be `airflow-config-smtp-password` instead of `airflow-variables-smtp-password`.

According to document [Configuring your environment with Secret Manager](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/secret-manager#configuring_your_environment_with), it suggest to use secret backend `airflow.providers.google.cloud.secrets.secret_manager.CloudSecretManagerBackend`.

And the document especially has a warning says

> Caution: Do not use airflow.contrib.secrets.gcp_secrets_manager.CloudSecretsManagerBackend because this value does not allow you to view logs on the Airflow web server UI.

And the document [Configure an SMTP password for a third-party SMTP service](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/configure-email#smtp_password) gives an example about how to store an SMTP password in Secret Manager:

```
echo -n "SMTP_PASSWORD" | gcloud beta secrets create \
  airflow-variables-smtp-password \
  --data-file=- \
  --replication-policy=automatic
```

It use `airflow-variables` as prefix of the secret variable.

But the problem is, the backend `airflow.providers.google.cloud.secrets.secret_manager.CloudSecretManagerBackend` use prefix `airflow-config` for secret configs

in source code `/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/providers/google/cloud/secrets/secret_manager.py`

```py
    def __init__(
        ...
        variables_prefix: str = "airflow-variables",
        config_prefix: str = "airflow-config",
        ...
    ) -> None:
        ...

    def get_variable(self, key: str) -> Optional[str]:
        ...
        return self._get_secret(self.variables_prefix, key)

    def get_config(self, key: str) -> Optional[str]:
        ...
        return self._get_secret(self.config_prefix, key)
```

And the backend `airflow.contrib.secrets.gcp_secrets_manager.CloudSecretsManagerBackend` use prefix `airflow-variables` for both variables and secret configs

in source code `/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/contrib/secrets/gcp_secrets_manager.py`

```py
    def __init__(
        ...
        variables_prefix="airflow-variables",  # type: str
        ...
    ):
        ...

    def get_variable(self, key):
        ...
        return self._get_secret(self.variables_prefix, key)
```

So if you are following the suggested backend, then you should use `airflow-config` as secret variable prefix. In my case, it should be `airflow-config-smtp-password` in secret manager.